# Histogram and Distance methode

Tags: distance, histogram

Can you explain that a histogram can find the degree of similarity in the image? for example, the euclidean distance.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_histogram
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance

so base on color look at the stats of color the most for color and how it is trough out the image

euclidean distance is the different between the two points so

1 color and amount of color different 
and 
2 how fare the pixels are a part count pixels  [x=2 y=4 z=2] [x=4 y=-4 z=9] = [x=>2 y=>8 z=7]

Comment: whether the value of the probability histogram of the two images used on the euclidean distance to calculate the level of similarity of the images?